# JS: innerHTML and DOM aren't cooperating

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I've noticed a funny behavior and was wondering if anybody could shed some light on the reason.

It breaks down like this:

- I've added a `div` and a `button` using Javascript's `appendChild'.
- I add an `onclick` handler to the button, works fine
- I add-assign the `innerHTML` of the `div` to add some more content
- Button `onclick` stops working altogether

Here's a sample script:

```
var D = document.createElement("DIV"), B = document.createElement("BUTTON");
B.innerHTML = "Is it true?";
document.body.appendChild(D);
D.appendChild(B);

B.onclick = function() { alert("Elvis Lives!"); }
```

At this point, it works fine. Then, add this line:...

```
D.innerHTML += "What about Tupac?";
```

...and the button breaks.  So, I'm just using `appendChild` for all elements now.

But -

- Why is this happening ("seems like it should work :)  ")
- Is there a fix (besides appending all my extra elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a shortcut for creating DOM elements. When you append something to the outer div using `innerHTML`, this is what happens:

```
D.innerHTML += "What about Tupac?";
```

which is the same as,

```
D.innerHTML = D.innerHTML + "What about Tupac?";
```

which is the same as,

```
D.innerHTML = "<button>Is it true?</button>" + "What about Tupac?";
```

which finally becomes this,

```
D.innerHTML = "<button>Is it true?</button>What about Tupac?";
```

Now in the last step, we completely replaced the existing contents of the div, with a new string which contains HTML. As far as the DOM is concerned, it doesn't care whether a user typed the HTML by hand, or it came from calling `innerHTML` on a DOM node. All it cares about is, is that it has a string of HTML, which must be converted to a DOM. A new button element is created at this time, which is why the `onclick` stops working - it's not the same element anymore.

Answer (score 4):

(this is a lot of educated guessing) I think when you modify `D`'s `innerHTML`, the dom within `D` is destroyed and created from the new value. So when the new contents are constructed, you are getting a brand new `button`, which is not the same node as `B`. since you set the `onclick` handler via js and not by an attribute on the original element, the new `button` does not have that function reference. however `B` still works as can be demonstrated by calling

```
B.click();
```

after you append to `innerHTML`.

to prevent the thrashing of the dom within `D`, you can do this instead of using `innerHTML`:

```
D.appendChild(document.createTextNode("What about Tupac?"));
```

Comment: Sounds good to me but I may await a few other opinions.  Right, I'm using `appendChild` all over the place but `innerHTML` is just a few lines easier...

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just a test page - looks very strange - I can confirm your findings

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  var D = document.createElement("DIV"), B = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  D.id = "div1"
  B.innerHTML = "Is it true?";
  B.onclick = function() { alert("Elvis Lives!"); }
  D.appendChild(B);
  document.body.appendChild(D);
}
</script>
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += 'What about Tupac?'; return false">Click</a><br>
<a href="" onclick="alert(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick); return false">Test</a>
```

---

update: Lessons learned - be consistent.

This works as expected

```
<script>
window.onload=function() {
  var D = document.createElement("DIV");
  D.id = "div1"
  D.innerHTML = '<button onclick="alert(\'Elvis Lives!\')">Elvis</button>'
  document.body.appendChild(D);
}
</script>
<a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += 'What about Tupac?'; return false">Click</a><br>
```

Comment: I can't lower myself to even glimpse a strange looking page! What is this schlock? :)  Just kidding.  Thanks for the confirm...