# Why don't even handlers of dynamically inserted objects fire, even if they existed before the JavaScript ran?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I working on a client side app. I have been working non-stop for the past two days trying to figure what was going on.  My code is a bit too long to post to where I can explain what my problem is, I have narrowed where the problem is to the following scenario/question.  Here is what I have:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="hyper">Link</a>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("hyper").onclick = function(){alert("Link clicked!");};
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
</script>
```

This code works fine with out the without `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;`.

Why doesn't the event handler fire after `body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML;` even though the object, object.id are still the same and have loaded before the JavaScript?
*I have viewed the live DOM and all is the same.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you re-assign body.innerHTML, even if it's itself, the innerHTML changes and the DOM resets. That means, the `a#hyper` was ******re-created****** and its `onclick` became destroyed.

Self-assignment identity (note: said as a Haskeller) may not exist with getters and setters.\

Answer (score 1):

There is a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021123/js-innerhtml-and-dom-arent-cooperating) - basically the DOM is regenerated when Javascript re-inserts the HTML string.  The generated DOM may look the same, but programmatic references in Javascript have all been set to new addresses.

A solution for keeping event handlers and methods is here:

[javascript cloneNode and properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094811/javascript-clonenode-and-properties)

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I read the other posts and understood that even though the source is the same but the object to which the event handler has been set is destroyed.  But i failed to try to mimic the solution in my scenario. Can you write a snippet as to how it would using my example?